# compulsorily sourcing multiple setup files in same shell

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have 2 catkin workspaces cata_ws , catb_ws

in cata_ws I have a.launch of nodea which when evoked would call b.launch which is in package nodeb in catb_ws.

my problem is if I do a rospack find ( in .launch I would do find) of nodeb , I get resource not found error.

The error is understandable because I have overwritten workspaces and currently cata_ws setup configuration is at the top.

So how do I successfully encode find of nodeb. I am working on a large project hence I  need to compulsorily have separate workspaces.

Things I have tried and did not work.

1. set args=nodeb and value=pathtonodeb in a.launch . The problem is that in b.launch there are many includes to launches of other nodes in catb_ws
2. tried source [in cata_ws] devel/setup.sh --extends pathtocatb_ws/devel/setup.sh . Nope did not work

Thanks for the response.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222262/compulsorily-sourcing-multiple-setup-files-in-same-shell./) by [creative_cimmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/22559/creative_cimmons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Extending (or overlaying) a particular workspace is something that is most robustly done at *build* time, not afterwards.

The easiest way to get this working (assuming `cata_ws` overlays `catb_ws`) is to:

1. remove `build` and `devel` of both workspaces
2. start a new terminal and make sure to have only sourced whatever space `catb_ws` requires (ie: only the default Indigo `setup.bash` fi)
3. build `catb_ws` normally
4. source `catb_ws/devel/setup.bash`
5. *now* build `cata_ws` normally

If this is successful, you should now be able to (in a clean terminal fi) `source cata_ws/devel/setup.bash` and have `rospack find pkg_in_catb_ws` work.

This is with `catkin_make`. For `catkin_tools`, you may use the `--extend` option to `config` to make the overlaying more explicit (see [catkin config – Configure a Workspace - Explicitly Specifying Workspace Chaining](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html#explicitly-specifying-workspace-chaining)).

See also [Overlaying with catkin workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) and [Overlaying multiple catkin devel-spaces at the same time](http://answers.ros.org/question/64702/overlaying-multiple-catkin-devel-spaces-at-the-same-time/). That last Q&A is slightly dated, but lists some nice-to-know gotchas.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-12-10**:
I'd add a step 6: source `cata_ws/devel/setup.bash`. Now both `cata_ws` and `catb_ws` will be "active" with `cata_ws` overlayed on `catb_ws`. The `rospack` command should be able to find packages in either workspace after only sourcing the `cata_ws` setup.bash file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-10**:
I had a small typo in my answer: the last `source cat..` should've been `cata_ws`, not `catb_ws`. That was basically step 6, but not in the list.

Thanks.